# Python with Flexx cannot import name 'encodestring' from 'base64'

Tags: python, user-interface

I want to make a GUI with Python and Flexx seems like a good framework so I went to the documentation and started the tutorial there. I copied the code on the first example:

```
from flexx import flx

class Example(flx.Widget):

   def init(self):
       flx.Button(text='hello')
       flx.Button(text='world')
```

When running that code I get the error

```
File "C:\Users\axeld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flexx\flx.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .app import *
  File "C:\Users\axeld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flexx\app\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ._app import App, manager
  File "C:\Users\axeld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flexx\app\_app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from base64 import encodestring as encodebytes
ImportError: cannot import name 'encodestring' from 'base64' (C:\Users\axeld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\base64.py)
```

No idea why it happens or how to fix it. Please help

Comment: This module you're using doesn't seem to have been updated for recent Python versions - `base64.encodestring` has been deprecated since Python 3.1, and removed completely in 3.9.  You could fix it by changing that line to `from base64 import encodebytes`, but there are likely to be other version-related problems in the module.

Comment: That's probably the case. I just checked and the last time this module was updated was on 2007 so yeah, I don't think it's the best option. Thanks